# Getting original request in a REST method( springframework )

Tags: java, spring, http, rest

Is there a way to get the http request (header content) in a REST method? I'm using spring framework.

I want to build a new request from the current request to a different server in the REST method. This is more like a proxy/forwarding service - so I want to preserve the stuff I want in the original request.
I do not have much options -otherwise I would not have used REST for such stuff.

Does spring framework provide such interface?

For example - if I want to get hold of the request headers in the greeting method in the code below ( example code from spring.io )

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public @ResponseBody Greeting greeting(
            @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by REST handler?

Comment: Modified the question - it is my REST method

Comment: Still don't know what that is. Is it a `@RequestMapping` handler method? Show us an example.

Comment: Yes, that is what it is - @RequestMapping handler method. What do you call it otherwise? If you see this page: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ - The greeting method in GreetingController is what the method I'm talking about

Comment: Just a _handler method_ is fine. Keep in mind, that it's always easier to understand what you mean if you give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply give your handler method a parameter of type `HttpServletRequest` and Spring will provide it for you.

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public @ResponseBody Greeting greeting(
        @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, 
        HttpServletRequest request) {
```

[`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) provides a number of [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaders%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve HTTP headers.

Alternatively, Spring also provides the [`@RequestHeader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html) annotation that can be used like `@RequestParam` to retrieve a header from the HTTP request.